# Google map localization in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, localization, maps

I am developing an android application and I want to show user localized addresses in Google Map which is identical to [Maps App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps) where both English and Localized address will be shown.

[image]

However, As I integrated google map in my app, I can only see the english addresses and there is no localized address.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

[image]

I know there is way of changing the local to get localized addresses but I am specifically looking for addresses shown in both languages just like the Maps App.

Going through [Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#localize_your_map) I have found this

> When you add a MapView or MapFragment to your app, textual elements on the map are displayed in the appropriate language based on the user's device settings and location.

If it depends only on user's device settings and location then why in the same device I am observing two different behavior in these apps.

Comment: do you use GeoCoder?

Comment: No, I am not. I have implemented SupportMapFragment in xml.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this link What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android? for supported language.
& you can do this by simply changing the Locale of your application like this in your Splash or where you loading the maps.

```
String languageToLoad = "ar"; //here you can select your system local language too...
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```